# If no data in database then how to show "nodata" message in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How to show **No have any Data** message in List view page if no have any record in the database.

This is my ICouponRepository interface to inject in this controller.

```
IEnumerable<ManuItem> GetAllManuItem();
```

This is my SQLManuItemRepository to inherit ICouponRepository

```
public IEnumerable<ManuItem> GetAllManuItem()
    {
        try
        {
            return context.ManuItems.Include(mi => mi.Category)
                                    .Include(mi => mi.SubCategory)
                                    .Where(mi => mi.IsDelete == false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my Controller method

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var model = manuItemRepository.GetAllManuItem();
            if (model == null)
            {
                ViewBag.NoData = "No have any Data";
                return View();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Somthing was Worng" + ex.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Any change in this method or change in View?**

Comment: If `GetAllManuItem` returns a collection of items, then you may also want to check its `.Length` or `.Count` property: `if (model == null || model.Count == 0) { ViewBag.NoData = ...... }`. Furthermore, if this is about *menu items*, then spell it correctly as **Menu Item** please...

Comment: I understand, that the code is just snippet, but try/catch in GetAllManuItem looks redundant and hides errors. Better to allow exception to be catch in parent Index() to be explicitly reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly judge whether the returned model has data on the view. You can refer to the modified code below.

**Controller**

```
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                var model = new List<ManuItem>();
                try
                {
                    model = manuItemRepository.GetAllManuItem();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Somthing was Worng" + ex.Message;
                }
                return View(model);
            }
```

**View**

```
@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <p>No have any Data</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Have Data</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. This is work properly.